# How to configure a website to use .net 4 on IIS 6 with the MSBuild extension pack?

Tags: .net, iis, iis-6, msbuildextensionpack

I'm using msbuild extension pack (version 3.5) to create websites (on IIS version 6, Windows 2003).

I'm trying to configure the website to use .net framework version 4.0 (instead of the default 2.0 version).

When i do this using the IIS management pack, i select the properties of the virtual directory, go to the 'asp.net framework' tab, and select version 4.0.

How do is configure this using the tasks in the msbuild extension pack?

Answer (score 0):

Install the desired version of .net on the server and register the version

[See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Create a new App Pool for your application and assign it to you app in IIS

Comment: The link and advice I provided tells you how to configure any version of .net on a windows server (IIS6 or IIS7). Once the version of .net is installed and registered then you can configure your website to use that version.

Comment: How is this related to using the MSBuild Extension pack?